# Mapbox geometries get degraded when exported to tilesets

Tags: mapbox

I'm trying out Mapbox for the first time, and playing around with drawing some polygons in the dataset editor for export to a tileset. However, the polygons in the resulting tileset are not the same as what I create in the editor. The polygons are only very rough, simplified approximations of the originals.

In dataset editor:
[image]

In map layer as tileset export:
[image]

I understand that Mapbox does [vector simplification](https://www.mapbox.com/help/adjust-tileset-zoom-extent/) at certain zoom levels, but these changes are not zoom-dependent. I zoom in all the way and the shapes are still like this.

Moreover, such extreme degredation of the geometries makes tilesets essentially useless for features that require any sort of accuracy, like property lot lines.

Am I missing something, or is this really the expected behavior? Is there really no way to get accurate geometries into a tileset?

---

**UPDATE:** It appears this is only happening with shapes I create by drawing in the Mapbox data editor. So far the geometries that I've uploaded as geojson files have gotten converted to tilesets accurately...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because the maxzoom is too low.

When you create a Mapbox Tileset, either by uploading GeoJSON directly as a new Tileset, or by exporting your your Dataset to a Tileset, Mapbox will try to guess an appropriate minzoom and maxzoom of the Tileset.

Sometimes the min/max zoom's used aren't suitable for the map you're trying to create. Since there is no way to specify a maxzoom in either of the two approaches the only alternative is to create your Tileset locally with https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe specifying an appropriate maxzoom for your data and then uploading the resulting .mbtiles as a Mapbox Tileset.

Comment: Thanks for the information, though I don't understand on why maxzoom settings would degrade the polygons at *every* zoom level?

Comment: If the maxzoom is 5 then, any zoom > 5 is going to be degraded.

Comment: Right, so then that's not what's happening, because this is degraded at all zoom levels